# Javascript function called by timer, other things are happening

Tags: javascript, animation

I have a web page that animates a series of webcam photos. I preload all of the images into an array, and then call a function that displays the next image in the array, from SetInterval. The image display is as simple as `document.animImage.src = anims[frame].src;` and `frame` is incremented each call (and bounds checked).

However, each time through the loop, when it recycles to 0, the web page pauses, a bunch of stuff gets downloaded (but not all the images, maybe 25-26 of them), 
...and then it runs through them again. I'm trying to figure out the pause. It is downloading additional resources but I don't understand why.

I load the images with

```
        $directory = "./";
        $images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        imageLoad(<?php echo json_encode($images); ?>);
    </script>
```

and then

```
    function imageLoad(images)
        {
            document.timeout_state = 1;
            images.sort();
            length = images.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) 
            {
                anims[i] = new Image();
                anims[i].src = images[i];
            }   
            document.timeout_state = 0;
        }
```

And finally the timer called function to animate the frames is

```
        function animator() 
        {
            frame =  (frame + 1);
            if (frame > length)
            {
                frame = 0;
            }

            if (document.timeout_state == 0)
            {
                document.animImage.src = anims[frame].src;
            }   

        }
```

You can see the page at http://www.PatrickHarvey.com/froghollow (links to the page). Set the interval to 10 ms and you can see the odd pause at the end of the cycle.

Comment: Take google chrome JS debugger and debug through your code. PS: the error is not reproducible here.

Comment: Try checking the values for each variable/property in that statement. You can do it with the debugger, or with `console.log`.

Comment: `if (frame > length)` should be `if (frame >= length)`, otherwise `anims[frame]` will run past the end of the array. What do you think `document.timeout_state` is doing within your `imageLoad()` function? Note that that function contains *only* synchronous code, and it doesn't wait for the images to finish loading...

Comment: Yes, the error was corrected. The timeout_state variable was an attempt to prevent access to array elements that had not yet been filled, it is superfluous. You can reproduce the issue with resources by setting the timeout value to 10 milliseconds, then you can see an odd pause at the end of the cycle before it restarts. I used the debugger and stepped through everything. I can't figure out what is happening, it seems to be off in some ob() function, I have no idea how it is getting there. It seems to be reloading later images.

Comment: Okay it looks like this issue occurs in Safari but not in Firefox nor Chrome. What an odd behavior.